# ipython automplete options font and background colors with not enough contrast

Tags: ipython

For some reason the autocomplete menu on `ipython` shows options with pinkish font and off-white color, what makes it very hard to read.

Is there any reason why those colors are being chosen? Instead of the more readable ones

What is the preferred way to change the colors to make them more readable?

[image: ipython autocomplete options highlight]